# How do I do a first-in-first-out system in Flutter/Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an app very similar to an inventory management system. My roadblock right now is the number of queries allowed in firestore, because it doesn't allow multiple .where()'s.

So using the inventory management system concept, we create a collection:

We'll Call it **'InventoryCollection'**. Let's say it has 3 fields:

```
- ItemID
- ItemName
- DateAdded
```

Each document in **'InventoryCollection'** has a sub collection called **'PurchaseHistory'**:
It has fields:

```
- PurchaseID (auto generated document id)
- ItemID (from parent collection document)
- PurchaseDate
- Quantity
```

**Dilemma:** How to deduct the Quantity of an Item using the concept of first in first out?
So let's say Item1 has **4** PurchseHistory data. and let's say one of them has 0 quantity because they were already sold.

```
- PurchaseID: 12340 
- ItemID: 00001
- PurchaseDate: 01-feb-2021
- Quantity: 0

- PurchaseID: 12341(auto generated document id)
- ItemID: 00001
- PurchaseDate: 02-feb-2021
- Quantity: 10

- PurchaseID: 12342
- ItemID: 00001
- PurchaseDate: 03-feb-2021
- Quantity: 5

- PurchaseID: 12343
- ItemID: 00001
- PurchaseDate: 03-feb-2021
- Quantity: 15
```

I need to find a way to **retrieve the PurchaseId** 12341 to get the "First In" using the parameters below. I can then figure out a way to do the "First Out" on my own:

- get all PurchaseHistory Documents with the ItemID: 00001
- only get documents that has 1 or more Quantity
- sort the data by PurchaseDate so that the first result will be the entry from feb 2
- limit query result by 1 to only get the feb 2 document
- get the purchaseID of that document to be used in the method below:

```
void _deductQuantity(String itemId, String PurchaseID {
  final itemCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('InventoryCollection').doc(ItemId).collection('PurchaseHistory').doc(purchaseID);
  itemCollection.update({
    'Quantity':  _quantity - int.parse(_editItemQuantityController.text.trim()),
  });
}
```

In my mind, the query looks like this:

```
String purchaseIdStream;


   final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('InventoryCollection').doc(ItemId).collection('PurchaseHistory').doc();
    
    purchaseIdStream = await docRef
        .where('ItemId', isEqualTo: ItemId)
        .where('Quantity', isGreaterThan: 0)
        .orderBy('PurchaseDate')
        .get();
     var _id = purchaseIdStream.ref.documentID;
```

I fully understand firebase does not allow to orderby, if you don't have the field in a .where for purchasedate. So it's definitely not possible to do it on the code above. since I already have 2 where's and a 3rd where is not possible.

I understand that I have to do server side filtering instead of multiple .where's however, I am only a frontend dev. My understanding in backend concepts are very limited. So I need terrible guidance on how to implement this in dart/flutter.

Any advice will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I believe you can do that with CollectionGroup query https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use where for itemId and quantity, then do the rest of the filters in Dart:

```
var listOfDocs = await docRef
    .where('ItemId', isEqualTo: ItemId)
    .where('Quantity', isGreaterThan: 0)
    .get();

docs.sort((prev, next) => (prev.data()['PurchaseDate'] as Timestamp)
    .compareTo(next.data()['PurchaseDate'] as Timestamp));

final desiredDocId = docs.first.id;

print(desiredDocId);
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, the `.where()` attribute is only for `CollectionReference`, not `DocumentReference`. Remove the `.doc(ItemId)` in `docRef`. I think it should work after that.

If it doesn't, get the data and sort it manually, like this:

```
final purchaseIdList =
    await docRef.where('ItemId', isEqualTo: ItemId).where('Quantity', isGreaterThan: 0).get();
purchaseIdList.docs.sort((QueryDocumentSnapshot a, QueryDocumentSnapshot b) =>
    (a.data()['PurchaseHistory']['PurchaseDate'] as String)
        .compareTo(b.data()['PurchaseHistory']['PurchaseDate'] as String));
final fifoId = purchaseIdList.docs[0].get('PurchaseId');
```

If I'm missing something, do tell. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Wait, do you need it as a stream?

Comment: Thanks for your answer however, I don't need it as a stream. I just need to get the PurchaseID of the earliest document in Purchase history that has quantity after a button is pressed.

Comment: Well, my answer isn't a stream, lol. I just copied what you wrote. I'll edit that. The final value of `purchaseIdList` should be a sorted list of the purchaseHistory that you require. And `fifoId` is the `PurchaseId` of the earliest document.

Comment: And now I've edited the answer. Check it out and see if it's working

Comment: thanks! I apologize as I was at work when I responded I should have read it first before answering. but I had a chance to test your answers now and here are the results:

solution 1: removing itemId in collectionreference - this resulted to an error: The initial orderBy() field '[[FieldPath([PurchaseDate]), false]][0][0]' has to be the same as the where() field parameter 'FieldPath([quantity])' when an inequality operator is invoked.

solution 2: using your code resulted to this error: Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Comment: I'll be honest with ya. I've never really used the `.where()` or the `.orderBy()` attribute. Only the `.sort()`. So idk how to resolve the error you got in the first solution. However, I can probs help ya out with the 2nd one. Can ya tell me where exactly that error is coming from? Like, which variable is it talking bout and stuff?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) says that if a field is used in `orderBy`, it also should be used in the first `where`.

```
citiesRef.where("population", ">", 100000).orderBy("population").limit(2);
```